# How to get a specific tag in a DOMDocument in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have variable documents that I need to modify on the fly. For example, I could have a document as follows:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0"?-->
<item>
    <tag1></tag1>
</item>
<tag2>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
</tag2>
```

This is very simplified, but I have tags with the same name at different levels. I want to get the item tags within 'tag2'. The actual tags in the files I am given have unique IDs to differentiate them as well as some other attributes. I need to find the tag, comment it out, and save the xml. I was able to get DOMDocument to return the 'tag2' node, but I'm not sure how to access the item tags within that structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the kind of problem that PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) class excels at. First load the XML string using `loadHTML()` method, and then use an  XPath expression to traverse the DOM tree:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$item_tags = $xpath->query('//tag2/item');
foreach ($item_tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->tagName, PHP_EOL; // example
}
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/102792)

Comment: Yup - I'd generally go with XPath over `getElementsByTagName()` for something like this.

Comment: But I suggest evaluate(), not query(). It allows for xpath expressions that return scalars, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$tag= new DOMDocument();
$tag->loadHTML($string);

foreach ($tag->getElementsByTagName("tag") as $element) 
{
    echo $tag->saveXML($element);
}
?>
```

may be helps you .try it

Comment: The problem with `getElementsByTagName()` in this way is that it doesn't really care where those tags appear - so `getElementsByTagName('item')` would actually match all `/item` and `/tag2/item` which isn't exactly what the OP was after AIUI.

Answer (score 0):

```
$DOMNode -> attributes -> getNamedItem( 'yourAttribute' ) -> value;
```